# How to rebuild a table in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have some problems with rebuilding the table on my web-page when data is changing.
I Have function `getData` to reset all info from Api. The Point is Data is getting, but table is not rewriting. Although, i see that DataPicker parameter returns the last date, not which i've chosed (for example was 18 Jan 2023, I am choosing 27 Jan 2023 and returns 18 Jan 2023).

```js
const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
const [dataUpdated, setDataUpdated] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState([]) 
const [Infodate, setInfoDate] = useState(new Date())
const [date , setDate] = useState("2023-01-25") 
const [ resource, setResource ] = useState( _resource_to_ask ) 
const [ link, setLink ] = useState(MyLink) 

function LDStoDateString() {
  let string_to_search = Infodate.toLocaleDateString(); 
  let parts = string_to_search.split('.');
  let day = parts[0]; 
  let mes = parts[1];
  let year = parts[2]; 
  setDate(`${year}-${mes}-${day}`);
 }

async function getData() { 
  console.log("GetData called") 
  setData([]) 
  LDStoDateString()
  let link_to_fetch = `${link}/${resource}?data=${date}` 
  await axios.get(link_to_fetch).then((response) => { 
    console.log("Data is accepted") 
    let items: any = [] 
    response.data.forEach(element => { 
      console.log(element) 
      items.push({ name: element.Name, bool1 : 
      StringVSBool(element.bool1),}) 
    });
    setData(items);
    setLoadingData(false); 
   }); 
} 

function handleDatePickerChange() { 
  setLoadingData(true) 
}
 
function SettingData(date_new) { 
  setInfoDate(date_new)
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (loadingData) {
    getData(); 
  }
}, [date, ...data]); 

return ( 
  <div className="App"> 
  <DatePicker
    dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
    selected={Infodate}
    onChange={(date_new) => { SettingData(date_new) }}
  />
  { loadingData 
      ? ( <p>Loading Please wait...</p> )
      : <Table columns={cols} data={data} } />
   }
</div>
```

Why this is happening? How can i fix this to update table on some event?

Comment: `getData` depends on `date`, so `date` should be in `useEffect`'s second argument (dependency array). This will cause `getData` to be called every time `date` changes.

Comment: Understood.  It work's. Console.log(date) has been fixed. But Table still not rebuilded. Is this connected with arguments in useEffect too?

Answer (score 1):

So in React, the component rerenders in four cases. The cases are:

1. Parent rerenders
2. State changes
3. Context changes
4. Hooks changes

Now, your setData() should invoke the state change, and therefore it should trigger the element to rerender itself. Furthermore, since the parent component rerenders, should the table rerender now again with the new data.

Now the problem is most likely because JS doesn't consider your setData(items) to be a new array and therefore it thinks the state didn't change. JS doesn't actually go through the array, it just checks the reference.

You can try to spread your items to the state in order to force the creation of new reference like so

```
setData([...items])
```

Hope it helped! You can check if the table is rebuilt if you console.log inside it or use React devtools to record the rerenders.

Good reading on React component rerender: https://www.developerway.com/posts/react-re-renders-guide

Comment: If i do that - date becomes wrong again. It getting back to the value of Last render, not current.